# NativeScript cocoapods is not installed when using sudo

Tags: nativescript, sudo, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to setup a nativescript development environment on a mac.

I installed all the dependencies including cocoapods. When I run `tns doctor` it all checks out, but when I run `sudo -E tns doctor` - it says cocoapods is not installed or is not configured correctly.

I need this to work in sudo since using `npm run build:ios` says I have no permission.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever this happens to me I uninstall everything (tns, npm, node), and reinstall again.